# No compatible AMD Radeon GPU detected on Blender

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, blender

Good day all,

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to figure out what my gpu version exactly is.

1, Checking my system, it reads:

> Processor: AMD® Ryzen 3 2200u with radeon vega mobile gfx × 4
> Graphics: **AMD® Raven**

On that note: A youtuber showed how to install driver to change the Graphics to **AMD@Radeon** by using release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20  . I attempted this, and did crash the Ubuntu  ... I then did reinstall the OP ...

2. Lately, working on Blender Rendering function, I checked what Blender recognized:

> Cycle render devices: CUDA, OptiX, Open CL => "**No compatible GPUs found for path tracing, cycles will render on the CPU"**

[image]

3. Checking the tutorial "How to check current AMD Radeon driver version" on  linuxconfig.org  => amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation after running the commands up to: glxinfo -B, the terminal gives:

> Vendor: AMD (0x1002)
> Device: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.40.0, 5.11.0-22-generic, LLVM 11.0.1) (0x15dd)
> Complete set of commands and output: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/zwD8pVSmsM/

4. Finally, I did ask previously about  installing the right driver. The response was that Ubuntu 20.04 has already all the drivers pre-installed and I should not venture into doing this as (1) it wont improve much the performances (2) taking risk to create some conflicts ...

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. How do I check that my radeon GPU is operational? Is their a system monitor for the GPU?

Thx in advance for your input
x

Answer (score 1):

For AMD GPUs to work in Blender, you need to select OpenCL as the render device. Both CUDA and OptiX are proprietary Nvidia APIs. It also might be that your GPU just isn't supported by Blender.